# Inserting geography type into SQL Server database

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pyodbc

I want to write (MULTI)Polygons into a SSMS database via python/

```
insert_query  = f"""INSERT INTO [dbo].[{table_name}] ({column_names[0]}, {column_names[1]})
                VALUES (?, ?)"""

val = (postal_code, f'geography::STGeomFromText({geovlak} ,4326)')

cursor.execute(insert_query, val)
conn.commit()
```

If I print 1 instance of f'geography::STGeomFromText({geovlak} ,4326)' I get :

```
geography::STGeomFromText(POLYGON ((4.90638 52.3781, 4.90677 52.378, 4.90643 52.3771, 4.90642 52.3771, 4.90557 52.3772, 4.90549 52.3772, 4.90469 52.3774, 4.90435 52.3775, 4.90432 52.3775, 4.90423 52.3775, 4.90425 52.3776, 4.90427 52.3776, 4.9043 52.3776, 4.90437 52.3777, 4.90438 52.3777, 4.90438 52.3777, 4.90447 52.3778, 4.90448 52.3778, 4.90452 52.3778, 4.90452 52.3778, 4.9046 52.3778, 4.90472 52.3779, 4.9049 52.378, 4.905 52.3781, 4.90502 52.3781, 4.90504 52.3782, 4.90505 52.3782, 4.90509 52.3783, 4.90516 52.3783, 4.90521 52.3782, 4.90523 52.3782, 4.90618 52.3781, 4.90637 52.3781, 4.90638 52.3781)))
```

This seems good to me, but then the following error occurs.

```
'42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]


A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate 
    "geography": \r\nSystem.FormatException: 24114: The label geography::STGeomFro in the 
    input well-known text (WKT) is not valid. Valid labels are POINT, LINESTRING, POLYGON, 
    MULTIPOINT, MULTILINESTRING, MULTIPOLYGON, GEOMETRYCOLLECTION, CIRCULARSTRING, 
    COMPOUNDCURVE, CURVEPOLYGON and FULLGLOBE (geography Data Type 
    only).\r\nSystem.FormatException: \r\n   at 
   Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.OpenGisTypes.ParseLabel(String input)\r\n   at 
   Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.ParseTaggedText(OpenGisType type)\r\n   at 
   Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.Read(OpenGisType type, Int32 srid)\r\n   at 
   Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.ParseText(OpenGisType type, SqlChars taggedText, 
   Int32 srid)\r\n   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.GeographyFromText(OpenGisType 
   type, SqlChars taggedText, Int32 srid)\r\n   at 
   Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.Parse(SqlString s)\r\n. (6522) (SQLExecDirectW); 
   [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The statement has been 
   terminated. (3621)'
```

Comment: You *aren't* inserting in SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) you're inserting into a SQL Server **Database**. Also the code `[dbo].[{table_name}] ({column_names[0]}, {column_names[1]})` looks find open to injection. Why do you have dynamic object names?  Wrapping an injected value in delimit identifiers doesn't stop injection if you don't escape all the needed characters too.

Answer (score 0):

You are including the `STGeomFromText` function call in the parameter value. If you want to call the function on the `geovlak` text then you need to include the function call in the command text, e.g.,

```py
insert_query  = f"""INSERT INTO [dbo].[{table_name}] ( … )
                VALUES (?, geography::STGeomFromText(? ,4326))"""

val = (postal_code, geovlak)

cursor.execute(insert_query, val)
conn.commit()
```